# Deleting files from Azure Devops that no longer exist in the project

Tags: visual-studio

I have an issue where I seem to have lost a capability in Visual Studio during one of the upgrades.  I am now using version 17.4.4.

I used to be able to open up Source Control Explorer, compare a folder between which files are on the server and which ones are local, in the results I could right click on the files that exist only on the server, and click delete.  The file is then schedule for removal from the server on the next check-in.

Unfortunately I am now receiving the following error when I try and click delete, and nothing happens.

The item $/MainCodeBase/FolderName/FolderName/ProjectName/FileName.cs could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it.

Has anyone else seen this issue, or is this still working in VS 17.4.4 for you? Does anyone have a solution to this issue?